# How can I solve this PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

$\dfrac{\partial \hat{Q}}{\partial t} - \dfrac{Am}{\rho} \dfrac{\partial ^3Q}{\partial t \partial z^2} = 0$

I really do not know which method could I use to solve it!

Comment: Are $Q$ and $\hat{Q}$ distinct values? If yes, something needs to be added. If not, with assumption that there are boundary and initial values, you can rewrite it as
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left(Q-\frac{Am}{\rho}\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial z^2}\right)=0 $$

Now it's clear what to do

Comment: Thanks Cool. There are bc an iv and yes $Q$ and $\hat{Q}$ are the same value. However, the solution is not so clear for me.. Is it a parabolic pde?

Comment: Are the coefficients or bc's time dependent? Then you get a $2^{nd}$ order ODE at each time step: $Q(z,t)-\frac{Am}{\rho}(z,t)Q_{zz}=Q_0(z)-\frac{Am}{\rho}(z,0)Q_0''(z)$ where $Q_0=Q(z,0)$ is the ic.

Comment: Initial PDE must be examined very carefully, if you want to identify its type. But it's no matter since new equation is an ODE.